# Creating a randomly even distribution of two lists in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

let's asume I have two lists:

(1)

- plays baseball
- plays cricket
- plays tennis
- plays golf
- plays rugby

(2)

- Tim
- Steve
- Max

Now I would like to make a random, but mostly even distribution in this way:

- Tim plays rugby
- Steve plays tennis
- Tim plays baseball
- Max plays cricket
- Steve plays golf

I would like to avoid that e.g. Tim plays 3 or 4 sports and e.g. Max does not play any.

// EDIT: I would like to distribute the whole of List (1). So the absolute number of distributions is the length of list (1).

Is there a possibility of doing this in google sheets?

Best,
Florian

Comment: you left out one crucial detail I think.  How many "random" combinations are you looking to make?

Comment: You are right. Edited.

Comment: What do you mean by "randomly even distribution" when you also want to specify frequency of occurrence by "I would like to avoid that e.g. Tim plays 3 or 4 sports and e.g. Max does not play any."? Randomly even means the outcome is... *random*. And all the examples you want to avoid are valid. If you want premutation instead, then it should be a separate question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say your noun phrases are in column A and verb phrases are in column B. Empty cells are allowed.

In column C, every new sentence can be generated by

```
= join(" ",
       index(filter(A:A,A:A<>""),randbetween(1,counta(A:A)),1),
       index(filter(B:B,B:B<>""),randbetween(1,counta(B:B)),1))
```

"Drag", or spread, the formula as much as you need.

Note that non-empty cells with empty text are *not* ignored.

Comment: Okay so with this I always get a "failed to parse this formula" (#error). I switched the , for ; since I'm on the german version of google sheets.
Same problem.

Comment: @FlorianT. Ah I mixed up the order of inputs for `join()`. See edit

Comment: Thanks!
Okay, but what happened now is A is distinct (perfect), but I would like B to be evenly distributed or "nearly" distinct if you know what I mean?
Right now Tim almost plays all the sports, when the others don't get many.

Comment: @FlorianT. That is what *random* means. If you want to see the uniformity, have more sentences. As I mentioned when commenting to your question, a shuffle, or a permutation would change your question entirely.

Comment: @FlorianT. Please read how to and [share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311) so as you can be easier helped.